# How do you copy/paste from the clipboard in C++?

Tags: c++, copy, clipboard, paste

I'm still a C++ newbie who has only recently learned some file manipulation. I looked it up online and the codes given are way beyond my current skill. Is there a simple way to do this, or are there any good tutorials that can explain this from the very basics?

Comment: On what operating system? In what framework?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: What operating system, and, in the case of Linux what clipboard?

Comment: Interaction with the clipboard is not part of the (C++)-language standard. You have to use API functions of your operating system or the usually simplified access functions if you use a framework. You can use the Qt framework, delivered with huge amount of tutorials, but you have to learn about the usage of Qt. Hope that will help

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was OS dependent. I'm using 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: For a cross-platform way, using Qt, we can see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15742175

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In ***windows*** look at the following API:

- [OpenClipBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649048%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [EmptyClipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649037%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [SetClipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649051%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [CloseClipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649035%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [GetClipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649039%28VS.85%29.aspx)

An extensive discussion [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Obviously this topic is strongly operating system related. And if you are using some framework (ie MFC/ATL) you generally find some helper infrastructure. This reply refer to the lowest API level in WIndows. If you are planning to use MFC [have a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ca18w7k%28VS.80%29.aspx), if you prefer ATL [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhedazz8%28VS.71%29.aspx#_atl_cwindow_clipboard_methods).

Comment: And don't forget about [IsClipboardFormatAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms649047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: for simple `wstring` clipboard copy, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664890/copy-unicode-string-to-clipboard-isnt-working/68077157#68077157

Answer (score 10):

**There is no cross-platform way to do this in C++**

---

Now that we have that out of the way, [Felice Pollano's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436257/how-do-you-copy-paste-from-the-clipboard-in-c/6436321#6436321) answer provides the Windows API so you can manipulate the clipboard in Windows.

[Apple](http://developer.apple.com/) provides an example application named [ClipboardViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) and an entire reference to the [NSPasteBoard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the functionality it provides.

As for Linux, it depends on what windowing manager you are running.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **ClipboardXX** library for copy and pasting simple texts.
Just download `clipboardXX.hpp` from [github](https://github.com/Arian8j2/ClipboardXX) and copy it to your project path. Then follow its examples:

```cpp
#include "clipboard.hpp"
#include <string>

int main() {
    clipboardxx::clipboard clipboard;

    // copy
    clipboard << "text you wanna copy";

    // paste
    std::string paste_text;
    clipboard >> paste_text;
}
```

Comment: does not compile with bcc32

Answer (score 5):

There is a cross platform way to do this in C++, provided you are willing to use the Qt Library.

A solution for this is provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437290/2158002

Answer (score 0):

A demo example shown here:

```html
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QClipboard>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QString originalText = "My name is khan";
    ui->label_text_to_copied->setText(originalText);
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::copy_stuff);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::copy_stuff()
{
    QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
    QString text_to_be_copied = ui->label_text_to_copied->text();
    clipboard->setText(text_to_be_copied);
    ui->label_copy_status->setText("Copied!");
}
```

Answer (score -8):

If you are looking for a simle way to do this : simulate the keyboard combination ctrl + v and you are done with it. On all platforms.

Comment: Not every application supports `Ctrl`+`C`/`V` even on platforms where that combination is common for copy/paste. The reason I ended up at this question was because I need to *implement* copy/paste functionality for `Ctrl`+`C`/`V` in a Windows application.