# Copy to clipboard in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard

I want to copy some string to clipboard in my C++ application.
How can I do that?
Also is it possible to copy the formatting as well?
Thank You

Comment: This is largely platform-dependent.

Comment: Check This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436257/how-do-you-copy-paste-from-the-clipboard-in-c

Comment: What operating system you want to do such thing ?

Comment: I am developing my application using Qt & it doesnt seem to have that functionality.
Currently dealing with Windows, but will need for Ubuntu in future as well.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I edited your question to add the tags [Qt] and [clipboard].

Comment: @Cool_Coder This question I just asked might be relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436045/in-qt-how-can-i-can-i-register-a-qstring-to-my-systems-clipboard-both-quoted#40436045

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You said you use Qt in one of your comments.

Qt has the class [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qclipboard.html), which is what you want (bonus: this is cross-platform).

You can put almost anything you want, data is managed via MIME types. That means you can use your own data formatting in the clipboard, with a 'custom' MIME type. Note that formatting is usually done with html text (`text/html`), whereas plain text is in `text/plain` (for plain text Qt provides the function `text()`).

Comment: Interesting. When you're saying it's cross-platform, I suppose it still needs to be initialized/configured to a specific platform?

Comment: cross-platform because Qt is cross-platform. There still are some corner cases (ex: global mouse on X11), but for the common use it works the same on all supported platforms (which is at least Windows, Linux, Mac, and some phones). There is no manual initialization, all is done by Qt.

Comment: I didn't mean it has to be manual and can be set by the QT itself according to environment settings but the underlying implementation surely varies.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The user have nothing to initialize, but Qt have some large `#ifdef WIN ... #else ... #endif` parts in its code that do the work ;).