# Paste selection in console based editor

Tags: console-application, text-editor, windows-console

I have written a windows console based text-editor with C & I'm gonna add copy/paste feature to it.
Editor is made up of a doubly-linked list that each structure just contains one letter. editor gets letters, arrow keys, backspace, ... with getch function (which is found in conio.h) & uses their ascii code to recognize them.

when a selection is made and CRTL+C is pressed, the selection is copied to memory but I don't know where to get that copied text.

Hope I cleared the problem,
Thanks.

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436257/how-do-you-copy-paste-from-the-clipboard-in-c. Also: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/57178-copying-clipboard.html

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Wonderful links!